# Meaning of 2-chain cover of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I found its meaning as :

For a graph $G=(V,E)$, a
$2-chain$ cover of $G$ is a set of edge-disjoint 2-chains which covers the edges of $E$

Can anybody explain the meaning ? Examples are welcomed.

Encountered the term in this article  :  sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X97001039

Comment: 2-chain is not a standard concept. The context is missing. Where did you encounter this?

Comment: I encountered it in this article  : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X97001039

Comment: Here is the relevant definition from the paper itself: "A *2-chain* is a simple path of length 2."